# Is possible to get a POST value while a page is loading with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm programming a website and i need to get a POST value while the page is loading. If exists POST, is possible to create an another ajax post to get data from a 3rd page?

I'm using PHP, MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['whatever'])): ?>
    <script>
         //ajax code
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```